# Oracle co related query?

Tags: oracle

How does co-related query works? Does inner query iterate according to outer query rows? Suppose I have student table with only 1 ID columns with vlaues 1, 2, 3. Can any body gives pictorial example?

```
select count(*)
from student s where s.sid < any (select s1.id from student s1 where s1.id <  s.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The correlated subquery is (theoretically - without considering possible optimization) performed once for each row of the main table (s).

For the s.ID = 1 the subquery returns no row (s1.ID < 1 return nothing)

for the s.ID = 2 it returns 1 and (predicate s1.id < 2)

for the s.ID = 3 it returns 1,2

Therefore the first row (s.ID=1) is not selected (the subquery return no row),

for the second row (s.ID =2) the predicate is  `s.id <  any ( 1 )` which is rewritten to `s.id <  1` see rules for [ANY](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/all-any-some-comparison-conditions-in-sql) 
and the row is not selected as 2 < 1 is FALSE

for the  third row (s.ID = 3)  the predicate is  `s.id <  any ( 1,2 )` which is rewritten to `s.id <  1  OR s.id <  2` which is FLASE as well.

So the query

```
create table student as 
select rownum id from dual connect by level <= 3;

select *
from student s where s.id <  any (select s1.id from student s1 where s1.id < s.id);
```

**return empty result (no rows)**.